# Deshabilitar cookies al abrir pop up de pagina web con cookie?

Tags: php, script, url

Tengo un problema con las cookies y es que yo tengo una pagina web que quiero activar los usuarios via panel de administracion, pero el problema es que cuando estoy logueado en el panel de administracion y quiero activar los usuarios no puedo ya que estoy logueado como admin y la pagina donde se hace la activacion necesita no tener cookies ni estar logueado, me explico?, yo se que podria utilizar otro navegador para activar a los usuarios pero me gustaria que se pudiera hacer desde el panel de administracion, en concreto lo que necesito es un codigo php en el cual al momento de abrir la pagina de activacion en un pop up no cuente la cookie con la que estoy logueado como admin, este es el codigo de activacion:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="member">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10">Players Not Activated</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="on">#</td>
            <td class="on">ID</td>
            <td class="on">Username</td>
            <td class="on">Email</td>
            <td class="on">Tribe</td>
            <td class="on">Activation Code</td>
            <td class="on">Act 2??</td>
            <td class="on">Time</td>
            <td class="on">*PLAY*</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php


@include("GameEngine/config.php");
@include("GameEngine/Database.php");
@include("GameEngine/Admin/database.php");


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."activate";
            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["link"], $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $i++;
                if($row['tribe'] == 1) {$tribe = "Roman"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 2) {$tribe = "Teuton"; }
                elseif($row['tribe'] == 3) {$tribe = "Gaul"; }
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$i."</td>
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['username']."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"mailto:".$row['email']."\">".$row['email']."</a></td>
                    <td>".$tribe."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act']."</td>
                    <td>".$row['act2']."</td>
                    <td class=\"hab\">".date('d:m:Y H:i', $row['timestamp'])."</td>
                    <td><a href=\"http://www.travianforce.com.es/s8/activate.php?code=".$row['act'].">Yes!</a></td>
                </tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

no se como hacer para poder activar a los usuarios

Comment: Hola Jose, ¿podrías poner algo de código que tienes para generar la página que comentas? Un saludo.

Comment: si ya lo coloque en la descripcion del tema, muchas gracias!